# ¿ Rango de números con type="text" y pattern?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo la siguiente validación:

Un input donde controlamos con un pattern que haya solo 4 cifras incluida la posibilidad que la cifra tenga 0 a la izquierda.

```
<input type="text" required title="Debe tener 4 digitos." pattern="\d{4}" minlength="4" maxlength="4" />
```

Pero necesito tambien controlar mediante pattern que esta cifra este dentro de un rango entre 0100 y 4599 incluido estos 2 numeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personalmente encuentro que mantener una regex compleja es costoso y prefiero usarlas con mesura, pero en este caso podrías hacer algo como

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required title="Debe tener 4 digitos." 
      pattern="(0[1-9]\d{2})|([1-3]\d{3})|(4[0-5]\d{2}))"
      minlength="4" maxlength="4" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Explicación

```
(0[1-9]\d{2}) Un 0 seguido de un número entre 1 y 9 más dos dígitos más
             | o

([1-3]         Un dígito entre 1 y 3
      \d{3})   seguido de 3 dígitos cualesquiera
            |  o
(4             un 4,
  [0-5]        seguido de un número entre 0 y 5
               \d{2}) seguido de dos dígitos cualesquiera
```

Puedes jugar con ella [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/ifoDc8/1)

Otra opción es crear una comprobación aparte, convirtiendo el texto a número. Es más código pero es más sencillo mantenerlo si los límites cambian:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('my-input');

const validacion = generaValidacion(100,4599);
input.addEventListener('input', validacion);

function generaValidacion(MIN,MAX) {
  return () => {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
    if (input.checkValidity()) { //pasa las validaciones básicas
      console.log('Validando valor', input.value);
      if (+input.value <= MAX && +input.value >= MIN) {
        console.log('Válido', +input.value);
        return true;
      }
    }
    console.log('Inválido', input.value);
    input.setCustomValidity('Introduce un valor entre 0100 y 4599');
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="my-input"><input type="text" id="my-input" maxlength="4" minlength="4" pattern="\d{4}">
  <button>OK</button>
<form>
```

Comment: No funciona porque el rango que quiero es de 0100 a 4599 y en este caso veo que el rango es de 0000 a 4599

Comment: No me di cuenta de que no era 0000, lo he actualizado

Comment: Ok funciona perfecto